# WinForm App not writing logs into a file created when data source in LinqPad

Tags: c#, winforms, linqpad, system.diagnostics

My WinForm GUI app (reporting) gets data from code that is in LinqPad. Means data source is another Library for this app. The logging works perfectly when I am running a LinqPad code itself. While with Reporting App, it creates the file but does not write anything. It does not log the tracing info that is coming from LinqPad source. I tried using both Config and without, the result was the same.

I tried all the relevant suggestion in StackOverflow, Codeproject and other sites including Microsoft. Due to my unique scenario, I could not find a helpful answer. Below code sits in LinqPad. What am I missing in my code?

```
var trace = new TraceSource("traceSource", SourceLevels.Verbose);
trace.Listeners.Remove("Default");
trace.Listeners.Add(new System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener("C:\\logs\\TextWriterOutput.log"));
trace.TraceInformation("TraceInfo");
trace.Flush();
```

I expect the output of "TraceInfo" written in the log file TextWriterOutput.log

Answer (score 0):

By default TRACE isn't defined in LinqPad

Try

```
#define TRACE
```

at the start of your script.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. It is in place. Thanks.